# How to bind a property with changes found in any of multiple RACObserves

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

The following code works fine:

```
[RACObserve(self.person, firstName)
 subscribeNext:^(id x) {
     self.descriptionText = [self concatenateInformation];
 }];
[RACObserve(self.person, lastName)
 subscribeNext:^(id x) {
     self.descriptionText = [self concatenateInformation];
 }];
[RACObserve(self.person, primitiveIntegerAge)
 subscribeNext:^(id x) {
     self.descriptionText = [self concatenateInformation];
 }];

 - (NSString *)concatenateInformation {
     return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@: %d", self.person.firstName, self.person.lastName, self.person.primitiveIntegerAge];
 }
```

Is there a way to allow any one of those RACObserve changes to just modify self.descriptionText using the RAC macro for binding it?

I have tried the following:

```
RAC(self, occupancySummaryText) =
[[RACSignal
  merge:@[
          RACObserve(self.person, firstName),
          RACObserve(self.person, lastName),
          RACObserve(self.person, primitiveIntegerAge) ]]
 map:^id(id value) {
     return [self concatenateInformation];
 }];
```

And while it works during application runtime, it will fail during an XCTest run with an error like this:

*** Assertion failure in __36-[RACStream(Operations) flattenMap:]_block_invoke_2(), /Pods/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACStream.m:75
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Value returned from -flattenMap: is not a stream:  name: '

How can I achieve the above in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of this problem, though I do not know the reason how it triggered this error.

In my Podfile, I have included ReactiveCocoa pod in both the application and test targets. Removing the ReactiveCocoa pod from the test target resolves the issue.

Original version having issues:

```
target 'Application' do
  pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 2.3'
end

target 'ApplicationTests' do
  pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 2.3'
end
```

Updated

```
target 'Application' do
  pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 2.3'
end

target 'ApplicationTests' do

end
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could enlighten me on why this is so.

Hope this is useful to anyone else who face the same issue.

Comment: Basically, the test target would have its own statically linked version of RAC, then the tests load the app, which has its own version of RAC. Now you have two version of RAC, which causes conflicts when doing runtime assertions.

Comment: Yes you are right. It had me reading up again about Cocoapod Podfile targets.